# Assign edge weights to a networkx graph using pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, graph, networkx, weighted-graph

I am contructing a networkx graph in python 3. I am using a pandas dataframe to supply the edges and nodes to the graph. Here is what I have done :

```
test = pd.read_csv("/home/Desktop/test_call1", delimiter = ';')

g_test = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(test, 'number', 'contactNumber', edge_attr='callDuration')
```

What I want is that the "callDuration" column of the pandas dataframe act as the weight of the edges for the networkx graph and the thickness of the edges also change accordingly.

I also want to get the 'n' maximum weighted edges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'number':['123','234','345'],'contactnumber':['234','345','123'],'callduration':[1,2,4]})

df

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'number','contactnumber', edge_attr='callduration')
durations = [i['callduration'] for i in dict(G.edges).values()]
labels = [i for i in dict(G.nodes).keys()]
labels = {i:i for i in dict(G.nodes).keys()}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax = ax, labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=durations, ax=ax)
_ = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have multiple rows where "number" and "contactnumber" columns have the same values and "callDuration column varies. For instance, the values are like {'number':['123','123','345'],'contactnumber':['234','234','567'],'callduration':[1,2,4]}).
So, I want to add up the callDuration for the first two rows so that they can be represented as a single edge in the graph. Please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Hi Scott. Well, I have carried out the adding of rows based on similarity of some attributes in pandas. It is completed. However, I am still finding it difficult to find out the edges with maximum weights. Is there a way to get 'n' maximum weighted edges??

Comment: Well, @AnandNautiyal you could simply query your input data frame for max callduration. `df[df.callduration.max() == df.callduration]`

Comment: Yes Scott, that can be done. But I wanted to use the edge properties for finding out the maximum as I will be using the graph object for finding trends later on. Thanks.

Comment: @AnandNautiyal Ok, I think you got your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52445069/6361531.

Answer (score 4):

Do not agree with what has been said. In the calcul of different metrics that takes into account the weight of each edges like the pagerank or the betweeness centrality your weight would not be taking into account if is store as an edge attributes.
Use graph.

`Add_edges(source, target, weight, *attrs)`