# Finding maximum weighted edge in a networkx graph in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx, graph-traversal

I want to find 'n' maximum weighted edges in a networkx graph. How can it be achieved. I have constructed a graph as follows :

```
g_test = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(new_df, 'number', 'contactNumber', edge_attr='callDuration')
```

Now, I want to find top 'n' edge weights, i.e. top 'n' callDurations. I also want to analyse this graph to find trends from it. Please help me how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your graph is stored as g you can access its edges, including their attributes using:

```
g.edges(data=True)
```

This returns a list of tuples. The first two entries are the nodes, and the third entry is a dictionary of the attributes, looking like this:

```
[(a,b,{"callDuration":10}),(a,c,{"callDuration":7})]
```

You can sort this list based the callDuration attribute like this:

```
sorted(g.edges(data=True),key= lambda x: x[2]['callDuration'],reverse=True)
```

Note we use reverse to see the largest callDuration edges first.

I'm afraid your second question is very broad - you can do a lot of things with networks! Have a look at some tutorials like this one:
https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/exploring-and-analyzing-network-data-with-python

Answer (score 5):

Let's try:

```
max(dict(g_test.edges).items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['callduration'])
```

To find the maximum weight edge in this graph network.