User actions graph layout calculation
So, I have a weighted directed graph. Each node represents a page in web site, each node represents user action on moving from one page to another, weight means the amount of users that have performed such action. I need to calculate a good informative layout for this graph, that will be informative for visual analysis, I want to see bottlenecks and popular user paths (there are start and end nodes). I want my solution to.be in python. What can I do?
Upd: I've tried Sugiyama, Kamada-Kawai and Fruchterman-Reingold algorythms, but they do not seem very informative, as my graph is strongly connected and they create a big unreadable mash (even in 1.5k edges with about 30 nodes)

It's not clear there is a good way to visually display a graph with that many nodes and edges.  There are good tools (like networkx) to find the highly traveled paths, if that's really your end goal.

@TimRoberts I do use networkx, what instruments of it can I use from it to find highly traveled paths and bottlenecks?

Here's one suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440518/finding-maximum-weighted-edge-in-a-networkx-graph-in-python

Are there any ready-to-go solutions using heuristic methods, such as genetic algorythms, or linear annealing? I mean cost functions that perform well
