# How to create a bipartite graph from a csv file

Tags: python, networkx, bipartite

I am trying to create a bipartite graph from an excel file that looks similar to this:

```
     xyz pqr tsu
abc  -1   1  -2 
def  -2  -1   2 
ghj   2  -1   1
```

For begining, I have tried the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\Dragos\Desktop\networkx project\proiect.csv')
G=nx.read_edgelist('proiect.csv', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=str)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

But I keep getting the error *Failed to convert edge data (['wage,carbon', 'tax,imigration,healthcare,voting,drugs,dc', 'statehood,abortion,UBI,wealthtax']) to dictionary.*

Right now I'm at a loss and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hi! Can you share the csv file you are reading?

Comment: Hello!
This is the file:https://easyupload.io/38bsr9

Comment: Try adding the correct separator ',' to read_edgelist (https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html).

Comment: Even after adding ',' to separate value, I still get the same error

Comment: Don't be cnfused, the error has changed. Now instead of 'wage,carbon' you have 'min wage' and 'carbon tax', that is, it is parsing the columns properly.

Comment: If you need us to help, please provide a more concrete explanation on what does -1 -2 1 2 mean.

Comment: @miquelvir and how could I proceed after the new error?
In my csv file I have the relationship between a politicians and policies: ranging from most progressive (-2), to progressive (-1), conservative(1) and most conservative(2). What I want to do is to show graphically this relationship between the two classes of nodes (politicians and policies).

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0):

First thing is loading the pandas dataframe

```
pd.read_csv(path, sep=',')
```

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

Then you need to create a new dataframe such that it follows [this format](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html).

```
>>> df
   weight  cost  0  b
0       4     7  A  D
1       7     1  B  A
2      10     9  C  E

G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 0, 'b', ['weight', 'cost'])
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400380/assign-edge-weights-to-a-networkx-graph-using-pandas-dataframe) as well.

Comment: I have added *sep=','* to my code and it still gives me the same error.